TypeScript Node package types do not compile after publishing to NPM: 'Could not find a declaration file for module'
I publicly published a small Node package, maps-backend-challenge, to npm (the code on GitHub is here).
I ran npm run build, which ran fine, and afterwards, npm publish. But when I import this module to a fresh TypeScript React project with yarn add maps-backend-challenge and try to use the exported function I get two errors:
ERROR in ./node_modules/maps-backend-challenge/dist/index.js 33:19-40
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './maps-api' in '/Users/<redacted>/code/fe-maps-search-2/node_modules/maps-backend-challenge/dist'

ERROR in src/App.tsx:4:36
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'maps-backend-challenge'. '/Users/<redacted>/code/fe-maps-search-2/node_modules/maps-backend-challenge/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/maps-backend-challenge` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'maps-backend-challenge';`
    2 | import logo from "./logo.svg";
    3 | import "./App.css";
  > 4 | import getAutoCompleteDetails from "maps-backend-challenge";
      |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    5 |
    6 | function App() {
    7 |   getAutoCompleteDetails();

I believe both of these are type-related. I did add a type definition file, index.d.ts and yet it doesn't seem to compile properly.
What else can I do?
I also found Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type but most of the answers seemed like "bandaid solutions". I'd prefer to have this library compiled and published properly so that it can be used by any client.
Here's the file structure:
├── dist
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── maps-api.js
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── maps-api.ts
└── tsconfig.json

And here's index.d.ts:
// index.d.ts
declare module "maps-backend-challenge" {
  export interface AutoCompleteDetails {
    placeId: string;
    streetName: string;
    streetNumber: string;
    countryCode: string;
    country: string;
    freeformAddress: string;
    municipality: string;
  }

  export function getAutoCompleteDetails(
    address: string,
    countryCode: string
  ): Promise<AutoCompleteDetails[]>;

  export function getPlaceAutocomplete(
    key: string,
    address: string,
    countryCode: string
  ): Promise<any>;
}


There's no ./dist/index.d.ts in what you've published.

Issue resolved thanks to @jonrsharpe!
I had to add a separate .npmignore file as the .gitignore ended up ignoring the bundled contents in my ./dist, too, when publishing to NPM. Saying explicitly what to and what not to ignore worked. I should looked more explicitly the published npm package instead of just keeping an eye on my local.
Here's the .npmignore I'm using:
# Ignore node_modules (already ignored by default by npm)
node_modules/

# Ignore TypeScript source files if you compile to JavaScript
src/

# Ignore test files
test/
__tests__/
*.spec.ts
*.test.ts

# Ignore build scripts, configs, and environment files
scripts/
build/
.env
*.log
*.sh

# Ignore configuration files (these are generally not needed in the final package)
tsconfig.json
.eslintrc.json
.prettierrc
jest.config.js
.vscode/

# Ignore local environment files or OS-generated files
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db

# Ignore npm and yarn lockfiles (optional, depending on your preference)
package-lock.json
yarn.lock

# Ignore git-related files
.git/
.gitignore

